# Why data is changed after uploading xml file PHP

Tags: php, xml, file, dom, upload

i have the code to upload xml file using dom.

```
if (!$dom->load($folderName . "/" . $fvalue)) {

echo "<br>".$fvalue." file is corrupt or Tags are not closed properly  ";

}
```

it uploads the file **BUT** after uploading, there are 3 whitespaces in the start of the file before any xml Tag. Problem is we download uploaded file and upload again. but with whitespaces in the start of the file, dom dont allow to upload the file as it is corrupted.(i check the validation of xml using xmlvalidation.com) which returns error because there are spaces at the start. if i remove space manually than no error.

**How i can upload the file without adding spaces at the start ?

I checked to remove spaces from file etc. but i dont want to do that. i want to upload the file without changing.**

Comment: are you shure that the spaces are created during upload. Maybe they were created during download.

Comment: after uploading the file, we show link of file to download. I have download from there and also from ftp server. its same, spaces in the start.

Comment: which tool do you use to upload the files ? if a ftp client and use a windows machine, then check your mode for uploading. maybe change from ascii to binary mode.

Comment: i upload via coding, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @steven what is the possible case that file will be changed on download?

Comment: Maybe the three characters is a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) and are there all the time, you just do not see them when viewing using you editor, but see them when "viewing" using PHP. You could check the contents of your file using a hex editor or just a text editor capable of showing the BOM.

Comment: for download i am using header and readfile. i have checked there is charset=utf-8 in header. for BOM it will always on the start on the file, what is possible solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was with downloading the file. after download there was some spaces in the start of the file. code was

```
header("Content-type: application/force-download; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=" . $downFileName);
readfile($filename);
```

i changed to this and it's working fine now.

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($downFileName));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($filename);
```